# Date time base filter in dynamodb with node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am working on a DynamoDB project with node js and I want to fetch some data between two dates. So what i can do for date base filter please provide any code sample in nodejs for this problem. You can assume that we have to fetch student admission between two dates.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Can you put some code do that anyone can help you?

Comment: @abdulbarik Till now i am working with unix time stamp with simple operator. for example where "dob <  timestamp and dob > timestamp" here saved data is also a time stamp. But now i want to convert it in "YYYY-MM-DD hh:ii:ss" format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BETWEEN` to filter the items between two dates.

> BETWEEN : Greater than or equal to the first value, and less than or
>   equal to the second value.

**Example params of Query API:-**

```
var params = {
    TableName : table,
    KeyConditionExpression : 'yearkey = :hkey and title = :rkey',
    FilterExpression : 'createdate between :val1 and :val2',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':hkey' : year_val,
        ':rkey' : title,
        ":val1" : "2010-12-21T16:42:31",
        ":val2" : "2010-12-21T17:42:35"
    }
};
```

**Database Item:-**

```
GetItem succeeded: {
  "Items": [
    {
      "createdate": "2010-12-21T17:42:34Z",
      "title": "The Big New Movie 2010",
      "yearkey": 2010,
      "info": {
        "rating": 0,
        "plot": "Nothing happens at all."
      }
    }
  ],
  "Count": 1,
  "ScannedCount": 1
}
```